# How does PCI-E 2.0 "double" the GT/s as opposed to PCI-E 1.0

Tags: pci-express

I've tried to search for this at a lot of places online except simply going and reading the 1000 page specsheet and comparing it with PCI-E 1.0

But quite simply put, how does PCI-E 2.0 achieve 5.0 GT/s as opposed to the 2.5 GT/s for PCI-E 1.0.

Comment: So you expect **us** to go and read the specsheet to answer **your** question?

Comment: Not at all! I was wondering if someone *already* knew and would be willing to share their preexisting knowledge. If that doesn't work out, *I* would go search out the 1000 page specsheet and post the answer here. :)

Comment: [PCIE Link Speeds and Bandwidth Capabilities](http://www.anandtech.com/show/2412/2)

Comment: So they did just double the clock rate. Thank you guest!

Answer (score 0):

As [guest](https://superuser.com/users/247996/guest) linked in a comment about. [AnandTech's article](http://www.anandtech.com/show/2412/2) attributes it to as the doubling of the clock speed used by the interconnect.

> PCI Express 2.0 builds upon PCI Express 1.x primarily through the
>   doubling of the clock rate to 5.0GHz (up from 2.5GHz).